# Junit cases on property load fails on command line build

Tags: command-line, junit

I have method in class with below code and I have written a junit for the same. This works fine when I right click -> run as -> junit in eclipse. But when run the application build in my command line "gradle clean build", it is failing the test case with the below error on the line of load.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
  at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
  at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
```

Any thoughts on this?

```
inputStream = ClassLoader
    .getSystemResourceAsStream("com/tgt/resources/file.properties");
fileProps = new Properties();
try {
    props.load(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Property file missing");
}
```

Comment: I think eclipse has defined a classpath for unit tests, so when you run it with eclipse, that is loaded with the dependencies the test needs. That would be a reason why the tests do not run in command line.

Comment: I kept thinking about this. let's say you have your code in src/main/java folder, when you run from console, the path is set to the project root folder, and the resource is searching starting at "com/tgt/..." instead of "src/main/java/com/tgt/..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure file.properties is in src/test/resources. Eclipse will find files in all sorts of places, even if it's not the correct place that gradle requires.